# local variable 'form' referenced before assignment error

Tags: python, django, forms

i am new to django 2.x .. trying to create blog project as a training  to me
i have a problem error 
UnboundLocalError at /create_post/
local variable 'form' referenced before assignment

this error will made me mad

this is my views.py file

```
# views.py
def add_post (request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = postform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            form=postform()
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'create_post.html', {})
```

and this my models.py file

```
# models.py
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now

# Create your models here.

class post (models.Model):
    Post_Title = models.CharField (max_length=200)
    Post_Image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post/statics/img/')
    Post_Text = models.TextField()
    Post_Date = models.DateTimeField(default=now, editable=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.Post_Title
```

this is my create_post.html file

```
# create_post.html
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit"}>save new post</button>
</form>
```

this is my forms.py file

```
# forms.py
from django import forms
from .models import *

class postform (forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = post
        fields = ['Post_Title', 'Post_Image', 'Post_Text']
```

this is the error what i got

```
UnboundLocalError at /create_post/
local variable 'form' referenced before assignment
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/create_post/
Django Version: 2.2.1
Exception Type: UnboundLocalError
Exception Value:    
local variable 'form' referenced before assignment
Exception Location: D:\PEPSI\PycharmProjects\bloggersystem\post\views.py in add_post, line 29
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Mohamed Abaas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['D:\\PEPSI\\PycharmProjects\\bloggersystem',
 'C:\\Users\\Mohamed '
 'Abaas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Mohamed '
 'Abaas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Mohamed Abaas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Mohamed Abaas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32',
 'C:\\Users\\Mohamed '
 'Abaas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 31 May 2019 18:28:50 +0000
```

i want to understand not only fix the code

can any body help ???!!!

Comment: think about what happens if `if request.method=='POST':` is false, the value of `form` will never be assigned before you try to use it, i.e. reference it.

Comment: yes thank you, found the error .. added `form = postform()` before `if request.method == 'POST':` to identify for as references variable .. but it did't saved to database .. i don't now why ???

Answer (score 2):

You did not define a `form` variable in case of a GET request. This is because you indented the `else` one too much:

```
def add_post (request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = postform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form=postform()
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'create_post.html', {})
```

Comment: yes thank you, found the error .. added `form = postform()` before `if request.method == 'POST':` to identify for as references variable .. but it did't saved to database .. i don't now why ???

Comment: @MohamedAbbase: you need to create a `postform(..)` with `request.POST`, if you did not create one after the `request.method == 'POST'`, then you filled in an empty form and hence the `form.is_valid()` would be false.